# Plotting derivative of expnential in python - any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Tags: python, numpy, plot, sympy

Here's the code:
importing stuff

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
from sympy import symbols, diff

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

defining function and it's derivative

```
t = symbols('t')
B = sp.exp(t)

f = sp.diff(B, t)

print(f)
```

plot settings

```
fig1 = plt.figure(1)
ax1 = fig1.gca(projection='3d')

x, t, z = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-4, 4, 15),
                  np.linspace(0, 4, 10),
                  np.linspace(-4, 4, 15))

u = 0
v = 0
ax1.quiver(x, t, z, u, v, f, length = 0.07)

plt.show()
```

I keep getting the "can't convert to float" error, the program does print the derivative though and plots too when used without the derivative...

Comment: What's `sp`?  `sympy`, `scipy`?

Comment: "I keep getting" - does that mean you try the same thing over and over again, hoping that eventually it will work?  Where is the error?  What did you learn from the traceback?

Comment: i did mention import sympy as sp.

Comment: well i have tried a few things, using the exponent function from numpy for once which does calculate the derivative but does not plot it. i searched for the can't convert to float error on the internet and someone mentioned that it's caused by a function being from more than a single library. so i tried changing the order of imports etc. still doesn't work.

Comment: You define `t` as symbol, `t = symbols('t')`, but later overwrite it with a `linspace` definintion!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the traceback:

```
In [8]: ax1.quiver(x, t, z, u, v, f, length = 0.07)                             
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-66e3c3d2c6bf> in <module>
----> 1 ax1.quiver(x, t, z, u, v, f, length = 0.07)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py in quiver(self, length, arrow_length_ratio, pivot, normalize, *args, **kwargs)
   2620 
   2621         XYZ = np.column_stack(input_args[:3])
-> 2622         UVW = np.column_stack(input_args[3:argi]).astype(float)
   2623 
   2624         # Normalize rows of UVW

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sympy/core/expr.py in __float__(self)
    278         if result.is_number and result.as_real_imag()[1]:
    279             raise TypeError("can't convert complex to float")
--> 280         raise TypeError("can't convert expression to float")
    281 
    282     def __complex__(self):

TypeError: can't convert expression to float
```

Apparently it's trying to turn the `u,v,f` arguments into a numeric array.

```
In [9]: np.column_stack([u,v,f])                                                
Out[9]: array([[0, 0, exp(t)]], dtype=object)
```

`float(exp(t))` doesn't work.  `f` is a sympy expression; you can't turn it into a number.

The underlying problem is that you are trying to use a numeric plotting function to plot a symbolic expression.  `sympy` and `numpy` don't work together seamlessly.  Either use `sympy's` plotting tools, or convert your expression to a numeric one - an array of numbers evaluated at some points.

===

```
ax1.quiver(x, t, z, u, v, np.exp(t), length = 0.07)
```

does run.  `np.exp(t)` is an array, the same size as `t`.

===

Sympy plotting:

```
In [12]: from sympy.plotting import plot                                        

In [13]: plot(f)                                                                
Out[13]: <sympy.plotting.plot.Plot at 0x7f02b0f99400>
```

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html

===

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html#lambdify

`lambdify` is a `sympy` tool for bridging the gap between sympy and numpy.  It generates a `numpy` (as default) function from the sympy expression:

```
In [27]: fn=lambdify(symbols('t'),f)                                            

In [28]: fn                                                                     
Out[28]: <function _lambdifygenerated(t)>

In [29]: fn(t).shape     # evaluate a the 3d array `t`                                                            
Out[29]: (10, 15, 15)
```

Now we have numeric array that works in `quiver`:

```
In [36]: ax1.quiver(x, t, z, u, v, fn(t), length = 0.07)                        
Out[36]: <mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Line3DCollection at 0x7f02b0f24e80>
```

Comment: well that's basically just plotting the exponent function though, i need to plot its derivative so that if i make changes to the original function it's derivative automatically gets updated

Comment: You need to explore `sympy` plotting, and `lambdify`.

Comment: Erm i'm sorry but i'm unable to understand how you are using sympy plotting. could you please explain it with a  simple example? i'm all at seas here and i've tried looking up at sympy's documentation for lambdify but that gives me no idea. Any help would be much appreciated here.

Comment: `f` is your derivative - the example is plotting the derivative (which is the same as the function for `exp(t)`. For arbitrary function, replace `exp(T)` with your desired function using `T` instead of `t` in: `T=Symbols('t'); func=exp(T); ax1.quiver(x, t, z, u, v, lambdify(T, sp.diff(func(T).T), length = 0.07)`